# Linking the Cells of a spreadsheet like excel to be able to perform formulas c#. Eg: A1 +C8

Tags: c#, arrays, object, cell, spreadsheet

In Our assignment we were given a task to create a new spreadsheet program with a 26 x 26 grid of textboxes without importing anything and make use of array (in my case I Used array of objects).

I created a 2 d array of objects containing size of grid (27x27). the reason of it being 27 instead of 26 is because the first row and column is to show the ABCDE etc and 12345 etc of the rows and columns.

now the rows indexation I had no problem because it is numeric. however, the letters I solved by creating a string array with alphabet from a to z and entering them through a for loop and it worked.

Now the next step is to be able to link the cells, however, I am a bit stumped, because people told me I have to use Ascii or smthin.

Can anyone help me plz on how to achieve the cell links?

I have been able to past the name of each cell using this code but I fear I just filled the .Text of the cells not the cells name per se:

```
for (int x = 1; x < TwoDArrayCells.GetLength(0); x++) //nested loop to create the grid of textboxes.
            {
                for (int y = 1; y < TwoDArrayCells.GetLength(1); y++)
                {
                    Cells CellFields = new Cells(Name = $"{AlphabetRow[x]}{y}", x, y + 3); // called a new cell named CellFields.

                    CellFields.Text = Name;//Change to location if you wise to take 

                    this.Controls.Add(CellFields);                    
                }
            }
```

The result I would like is to be able to after this be able to link cells. meaning if I insert in a text box A1 + A2 it knows that a1 is the first box in the first row of first column and the a2 is the box in the second row of the first column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Columns can be A-Z only (Capitals), You can extract the column index and row index as follows:
Given a cell, `string cell = "A2";`
  - the column index: `int column = cell[0] - 'A' + 1;`
  - the row index: `int row = Convert.ToInt32(cell.Substring(1));`

Explanation: for the column, take the first letter, subtract it from 'A' (the subtraction will be performed on the assci codes of the characters) and add 1 since your actual cells are stored starting from index 1. for the row, just parse the rest of the string to int.

Comment: im sorry I didn't understand any of that :/.

I Have declared these:

        public int SizeOfGrid = 27;
        public object[,] TwoDArrayCells = new object[0, 0];
        public string[] AlphabetRow = { "", "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z" };

and why the A + 1?

and am making use of a class called cells too in it I have cellfield (letter) and (cell number)

Comment: TwoDArrayCells  should be [SizeOfGrid,SizeOfGrid] not [0,0]. Please provide the code for the class

Comment: public class Cells : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
{
public string Cellfield{get;set;}
public int CellNumber{get;set;}
public int CellFieldLocation{get;set;}

public Cells(string Cellfield, int CellNumber = 0)
{
this.Cellfield = Cellfield;
this.CellNumber = CellNumber;
}
public Cells(int y)
{
this.Location =   new System.Drawing.Point(100 * y);
}
public Cells(int y, int x)
{
this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100 * y, 20 * x);
}
public Cells(string Cellfield, int y, int x)
{
this.Cellfield = Cellfield;
this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100 * y, 20 * x);
}